# Finding questions which are Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I was wanting to see all posts at GIS.SE that have been flagged as community wiki.  I found the solution [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37652/where-can-i-see-the-list-of-new-community-wiki-questions/37653#37653) -  it's an advanced search option:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1

IMO, the community wiki can be improved.  This would be easier if the CW was more visible.

Additionally we could add a paragraph to the [FAQ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq) describing the wikification process.  Many "List of X" type questions border on product promotion.  I don't think we want to discourage these.  Instead, maybe we could start some "List of List of X" types of wiki questions, and provide a link to it from the FAQ.  Stakeholders of products mentioned in a list are not motivated by reputation.  There needs to be an easier way for them to find the wiki questions though.  As things stand now, it seems like many wiki questions fall off the radar.

For example, "*What GIS Software is available*?" could be a wiki question with links to "*What Raster GIS software is available*?", "*What vector GIS software is available?*" etc. Publishers of new software products would find the appropriate wiki question and list their product in it.

**Update**

What if SE changed the site so that any mention of "Community Wiki" would be replaced with a link to the search of [community wiki pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki:1).

[image]

Comment: Could the site not have a link like  "Wiki" beside the "Questions Tags Users.... Ask Question" to enable one to scroll/search through those that have been tagged as a community wiki?

Comment: I was wondering myself what the community wiki checkbox does. I think that this feature should be documented in the FAQ and a link should be added to the header where it's easy to find it.

Comment: Why not put a 'wiki' link in the top menu bar next to the 'meta' link??

Comment: Any implementation of the feature request part of this question would need to come via [meta.se] and, I think be unlikely to succeed (with CW being largely out of vogue nowadays), so I have set [meta-tag:status-declined] here.

Answer (score 1):

As [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162068/215590) at [Is there a way to search for community wiki 'questions'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38823)

> The correct way to do this now is `wiki:yes` (or `wiki:1`) and `is:question`

e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion